# Basic Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus

I feel stupid asking this, but how would one apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus here (trying to find $f$):
$$
\frac{d}{d x} \int_{3}^{x} f(t)^{2} d x
$$

I would tend to think that with the $d x$ in the integral something wouldn't work... I'm just lost here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it's a typo and that they want you to compute $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_3^xf(t)^2\,\mathrm dt$.

Otherwise, you can say that $\displaystyle\int_3^xf(t)^2\,\mathrm dx=f(t)^2(x-3)$ and that therefore$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_3^xf(t)^2\,\mathrm dx=f(t)^2.$$

Comment: That's what I want to think, but I have taken this question straight of an old exam at my University so I would tend to think/hope it's not the case '^^

Comment: I've added another possibility to my answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you justify this: $\displaystyle\int_3^xf(t)^2\,\mathrm dx=f(t)^2(x-3)$?

Comment: For any constant $c$, $\int_a^bc\,\mathrm dx=(b-a)c$. In this context, $f(t)^2$ is constant, since it doesn't depend on $x$.

Comment: Ah yes, $f(t)^2$ is constant, it makes sense !

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous, then

$$\frac{d}{d x} \int_{3}^{x} f(t)^{2} d x= f(x)^2,$$

by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: That would be correct if we had $\mathrm dt$ instead of $\mathrm dx$.

Comment: @ Jose: I was blind ....